# Is it possible to add a footer to the MaterialDateRange Picker?

Tags: android, calendar, material-design, material-components-android

I'm pretty sure this is impossible, but I just wanted to check before I use a 3rd party library.  The DatePicker doesn't really let you customize the UI, and it's basically a full screen DialogFragment so putting something above or below (or even on top) doesn't seem to be an option.

My calendar currently looks like this:

[image]

But I would like it to look like this design doc with a footer at the bottom. Let me know if you have any ideas, because I'm out of them.  Thanks!

[image]

```
   val builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()
      .setTheme(R.style.ThemeOverlay_MaterialComponents_MaterialCalendar_Fullscreen)
      .setCalendarConstraints(
        CalendarConstraints.Builder()
          .setStart(Date().time)
          .setEnd(oneYearFrom().time)
          .setValidator(AvailabilityValidator(it.unavailableDays)).build()
      )
    builder.setInputMode(MaterialDatePicker.INPUT_MODE_CALENDAR)
    builder.build().show(requireActivity().supportFragmentManager, TAG_DATE_RANGE_PICKER)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to add a footer to the `MaterialDateRangePicker` is to get access to the Picker root View and from there you can find the `Picker FrameLayout Container` (with Id `app:id/mtrl_calendar_frame`) and get access to its child View the `Vertical LinearLayout Container` which contains of three children: (a Days-`GridView`, a `Separator-View` and a `RecyclerView`) in a vertical orientation. What you want is to add a footer below the RecyclerView. Because the parent is a LinearLayout you can add the `weight` attribute to all its children to be `weight=0` except the `RecyclerView` (which render the months) to be `weight=1` to get all the remaining space.

To access the Picker root View you have to observe the `MaterialDatePicker` (DialogFragment) lifecycle and add the footer View in `onStart()` of DialogFragment. For this purpose you can use the `DefaultLifecycleObserver`.

Below is full working example to add a footer View:

```
private fun showRangeDatePicker() {

    //initialize dateRangePicker
    val builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()
    builder.setTheme(R.style.ThemeOverlay_MaterialComponents_MaterialCalendar_Fullscreen)

    //set CalendarConstraints
    val constraintsBuilder = CalendarConstraints.Builder()
    val c: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
    constraintsBuilder.setStart(c.getTimeInMillis())
    c.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1)
    constraintsBuilder.setEnd(c.getTimeInMillis())
    builder.setCalendarConstraints(constraintsBuilder.build())

    //set InputMode and Title
    builder.setInputMode(MaterialDatePicker.INPUT_MODE_CALENDAR)
    builder.setTitleText("Pick dates")

    //get MaterialDatePicker instance and set a lifecycle Observer to listen for DialogFragment lifecycle
    //DefaultLifecycleObserver needs androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0 and add the FooterView in onStart of DialogFragment
    val picker: MaterialDatePicker<*> = builder.build()
    picker.lifecycle.addObserver(object : DefaultLifecycleObserver
    {
        override fun onCreate(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        }

        override fun onStart(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
            //add footerView in onStart of DialogFragment so you can access the picker.view
            addMyFooterView(picker)
        }

        override fun onResume(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        }

        override fun onDestroy(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
            //remove Lifecycle Observer
            picker.lifecycle.removeObserver(this)
        }
    })
    picker.show(supportFragmentManager, picker.toString())
}

private fun addMyFooterView(picker: MaterialDatePicker<*>) {

    //get the MaterialDatePicker root View
    val rootView = picker.view as LinearLayout
    //find the Picker FrameLayout Container with ID: app:id/mtrl_calendar_frame
    val frameLayout = rootView.findViewById<FrameLayout>(resources.getIdentifier("mtrl_calendar_frame", "id", packageName))
    //and get the Picker LinearLayout Container (which contains of 3 children: Days-GridView, Separator-View and a RecyclerView)
    val linearContainer = frameLayout.getChildAt(0) as LinearLayout

    //for each child in Vertical LinearLayout Container set the weight to RecyclerView to 1 and 0 to all others.
    //(This is necessary before adding the footerView to distribute correctly each children Height)
    for (i in 0 until linearContainer.childCount) {
        val v = linearContainer.getChildAt(i)
        val params = v.layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams
        params.weight = if (v is RecyclerView) 1f else 0f
        v.layoutParams = params
    }

    //and finally add the 4th child in the above linearContainer to be the FooterView
    val myFooterView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null)
    val myFooterViewHeight = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50f, resources.displayMetrics).toInt()
    myFooterView.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, myFooterViewHeight, 0f)
    myFooterView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
    linearContainer.addView(myFooterView)

    //set any FooterView click listeners
    myFooterView.findViewById<View>(R.id.textView2).setOnClickListener {}
}
```

Where `footer_layout` is your custom footer xml layout like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/separatorView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="Match exact dates" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="±1 day" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="±3 days" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Result:**

[image: date_picker_dialog]